# Is there a way to find the PackageFamilyName at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to figure out the PackageFamilyName (as appearing in the manifest) in runtime? I looked in /Program Files/WindowsApps and could not find the relevant string there. Could not find any API that would let me do this...

Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for [Package.Current.Id.FamilyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.familyname.ASPx)? I'm not familiar with the WinRT-framework.

Comment: Yes. MSDN blindness - kept looking for the full string (PackageFamilyName)... Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [PackageId.FamilyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.familyname.ASPx) which is available through the `Package.Current.Id.FamilyName` property.

Source: [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3671cec0-4bdb-4db9-bba1-0f463985e7bd/)