# Determine if C# application is running as a UWP app during run time if appx is made from C# application using makeappx tool

Tags: c#, uwp, appx, appxmanifest, makeappx

I have created appx for C# Desktop application using MakeAppx tool.
During runtime, when appx is launched, I want to check this is running as appx and not as console application.
Is there a simple runtime check one can do in C# to determine if you are running as a appx (which is packaged using makeappx tool) and not as console application?
.

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609643/determine-if-c-application-is-running-as-a-uwp-app-in-desktop-bridge-project) True, the one from the link is for C++, but [a similar call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333375/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-packagefamilyname-at-runtime) should be available in C# too.

There is also [this option](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/11/03/desktop-bridge-identify-the-applications-context/) present on the MSDN forums.

Comment: exactly but I am not able to get same call in C# to have current package full name.GetCurrentPackageFullName function is available in C++ only.